# PayPal IPN notifies with protection_eligibility=Ineligible

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

This is in a custom PHP eCommerce application.  I have no problem receiving and verifying a PayPal IPN response, but it never returns with seller protection eligibility.

This is the generated IPN submission form:

*the data has been replaced with dummy data for this question, but it is legitimate data in the application*

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order #123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="123456789">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Smith">
    <input type="hidden" name="contact_phone" value="123 123 1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_country" value="Canada">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_country_code" value="CA">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_city" value="Test City">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_name" value="John Smith">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_state" value="Provice">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_street" value="123 Test Street">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_zip" value="A1B 2C3">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_status" value="confirmed">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://custom-ecommerce-app.com/thank-you.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="protection_eligibility" value="SellerProtection">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://custom-ecommerce-app.com/paypal-ipn-notify.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@custom-ecommerce-app.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
</form>
```

In the IPN response received, `protection_eligibility` is always `Ineligible`.  This occurs with or without the sandbox.  The business/recipient account is configured for seller protection.

I've tried entering generating the submission form with address information that is identical to the profile information of the sandbox customer account, and I get the same result (`Ineligible`).

What do I need to change in my account or submission form for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

`no_shipping` must have a value of `0` (prompt for optional shipping address) or `2` (prompt for required shipping address).  Orders with no shipping cannot be eligible for seller protection.